# Checkered square table in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Sometimes you need a checkered data structure, for example if you model a chess board. The simplest way to represent checkered data is via list of lists.

```
[[0,1,0],
 [1,0,1],
 [0,1,0]]
```

The above is the example of a checkered list. My first attempt:

```
import Data.List

checker :: Integral i => i -> a -> a -> [[a]]
checker n a b = genericTake n $ intersperse (genericTake n xs2) $ repeat (genericTake n xs1)
  where xs1 = checker' a b
        xs2 = drop 1 xs1

checker' :: a -> a -> [a]
checker' a b = intersperse b $ repeat a
```

The code is verbose, while the result is correct:

```
*Main> checker 5 0 1
[[0,1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1,0]]
```

How do i write a function to create such a list with arbitrary size in Haskell?

Comment: `checker = tails $ cycle [0,1]` then trivially `take n . map (take n)`

Comment: Why not put it as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
evenRow = 0:oddRow                -- evenRow = 0:1:evenRow
oddRow  = 1:evenRow
board   = evenRow:oddRow:board
```

Here's an infinite checkered board. Saw off any rectangular part:

```
smallBoard = take 17 $ map (take 11) board
```

Parameterize this as needed.

EDIT: I haven't used `cycle` here for the sake of illustration. In real code you probably want it:

```
board = cycle [cycle [0,1], cycle [1,0]]
```

It's much shorter but frankly looks fairly cryptic.

Comment: This is really clever. I think the cycle version is actually easier to understand.

Comment: Why not `evenRow = 0:oddRow`?